# Characters changing from CSV file to PHP, preg_match_all failing because of it

Tags: encoding

In my __construct() function I already have a header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8') call in my file, so UTF-8 on the page is already being set. The problem is I'm getting strings back like this:

> Chair or Bag: 12" W x 3 Â¼" H â�¢ Chair: Standard Front, Optional Back or Bag: Add $1.00(G) per piece, per position. Standard Imprint Area is the Chair Front. Optional Imprint Area is the Chair Back or Bag. Imprint on Standard Location Unless Otherwise Specified on Order. For Printing on Multiple Positions, Add $50.00(G) Set Up Plus $1.00(G) Per Piece.

When in the CSV File they look like this:

> Chair or Bag: 12" W x 3 ¼" H • Chair: Standard Front, Optional Back or Bag: Add $1.00(G) per piece, per position. Standard Imprint Area is the Chair Front. Optional Imprint Area is the Chair Back or Bag. Imprint on Standard Location Unless Otherwise Specified on Order. For Printing on Multiple Positions, Add $50.00(G) Set Up Plus $1.00(G) Per Piece.

.... so, my preg_match_all is messing up since what I'm trying to match is the bit with characters [ Chair or Bag: 12" W x 3 ¼" H ] with this pattern:

> /(([A-Za-z -0-9]*?): )?((\d* .?|\d*)" W x (\d* .?|\d*)" H)/

My question is, is there a way or function to keep the encoding the same when reading the file with fgetcsv() because the change in characters is messing up the preg_match_all function?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the "*" on your first "\d".